# Socket send works only sometimes in infinite loop (C)

Tags: c, sockets, fpga, dma, petalinux

I'm setting up a prototype for a DAQ system for Zynq FPGAs. I receive data from a server through ethernet, write it to a FIFO using the DMA and viceversa using two different pthreads. However, the send operation hangs, and after some iterations, it performs correctly then hangs again, meanwhile the `recv` operations succeedes and fills the FIFO.

Sometimes the threads worked as expected only if some printf where present or not, so I'm temporarily printing to stderr.

Sorry for the shameful code, but I tried replacing almost every line by now to spot the problem.

```c
void *sender(void *params) {

    arguments *args = params;

    if (args->head == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Head pointer not valid\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (args->tail == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Tail pointer not valid\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (args->virtual_address == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] AXI DMA register pointer not valid\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (args->virtual_buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Send buffer pointer not valid\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    unsigned long int units_sent = 0;

    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(args->lock);
        fprintf(stderr, "[*] Send   Head: %d    Tail: %d\n", *(args->head), *(args->tail));
        if (*(args->head) != *(args->tail)) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
            int remaining = args->buffsize;
            int sent = 0;
            pthread_mutex_lock(args->lock);
            int src = FIFO_ADDR + (*(args->tail)) * args->buffsize;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
            if (args->verbose > 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[*] Sender: DMA is transferring data from 0x%x to 0x%x\n", src, SEND_ADDR);
            }
            unsigned int length = args->buffsize;
            unsigned int verb = args->verbose > 2 ? 1 : 0;
            pthread_mutex_lock(args->lock);
            while (remaining > 0) {
                length = remaining < MAX_TRANSF ? remaining : remaining % MAX_TRANSF;
                DMATransfer(args->virtual_address, src + sent, SEND_ADDR, length, verb);
                remaining -= args->buffsize;
                sent += remaining;
            }
            elements--;
            units_sent++;
            if (args->verbose > 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[*] %f elements in FIFO: %lu\n", ((double)(clock() - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, elements);
                fprintf(stderr, "[*] %f DMA tranfer to buffer: %d\n", ((double)(clock() - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, units_sent);
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
            remaining = args->buffsize;
            sent = 0;
            int result = 0;
            pthread_mutex_lock(args->lock);
            while (remaining > 0) {
                    result = send(args->sockfd, args->virtual_buffer + sent, remaining, 0);
                    if (result > 0) {
                        remaining -= result;
                        sent += remaining;
                    } else if (result < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error retrieving configuration from the server\n");
                    exit(0);
                    }
            }
            //memset(args->virtual_buffer, 0, args->buffsize);
            if (args->verbose > 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[*] %f Unit sent: %d\n", ((double)(clock() - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, units_sent);
            }
            if (args->verbose > 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[*] Packet retrieved");
            }
            if (args->verbose > 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, " content: ");
                memdump(args->virtual_buffer, args->buffsize);
            }
            if (args->verbose > 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\n");
            }
            *(args->tail) = (*(args->tail) + 1) % args->fifosize;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
            if (args->verbose > 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[*] %f CPU Usage: %d\n", ((double)(clock() - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, GetCPULoad());
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        if (argc < 3 || argc > 5) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: DAQTest [IP address] [fifo size]\nExample: DAQTest 192.168.1.81 64\n\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Optional flags:    -v  Verbose (print operations)\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       -vv Very verbose (also print data content)\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       -vvv    Extremely verbose (also print DMA info)\n\n");
                exit(0);
        }
    if (isValidIpAddress(argv[1]) == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Invalid ip address\n");
        exit(0);
    }
        int fifosize = atoi(argv[2]);
        if (fifosize < 0 || fifosize > 8192) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[-] Invalid fifo size\n");
                exit(0);
        }

    char verbose = 0;
    if (argc == 4) {
        if (strcmp(argv[3], "-v") == 0) {
            verbose = 1;
        } else if (strcmp(argv[3], "-vv") == 0) {
            verbose = 2;
        } else if (strcmp(argv[3], "-vvv") == 0) {
            verbose = 3;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] Unwanted parameter\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

        int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (-1 == sockfd) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[-] Socket creation failed\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    /*
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = TIMEOUT;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);
    */

        if (connect(sockfd, (SA * ) & servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[-] Connection failed\n");
                exit(0);
        }

    fprintf(stderr, "[+] Connected to the server\n");

    int buffsize = 0;
    char* recv_buffer = (char*)&buffsize;
    int remaining = sizeof(int);
    int received = 0;
    int result = 0;
    while (remaining > 0) {
            result = recv(sockfd, recv_buffer + received, remaining, 0);
            if (result > 0) {
                remaining -= result;
                received += result;
            } else if (result == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[-] Remote side closed his end of the connection before all data was received\n");
                exit(0);
            } else if (result < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error retrieving configuration from the server\n");
            exit(0);
            }
    }

    //fprintf(stderr, "[*] Page size: %ld\n", sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE));

        int dh = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

        unsigned int *virtual_address = mmap(NULL, 65535, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, VIRT_ADDR);
    unsigned int *virtual_sendbuff = mmap(NULL, buffsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, SEND_ADDR);
    unsigned int *virtual_recvbuff = mmap(NULL, buffsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, RECV_ADDR);
    unsigned int *virtual_fifo = mmap(NULL, (fifosize + 1) * buffsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dh, FIFO_ADDR);
    if (virtual_address == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] AXI DMA registers mmap failed\n");
    }
    if (virtual_sendbuff == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Send buffer mmap failed\n");
    }
    if (virtual_sendbuff == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Send buffer mmap failed\n");
    }
    if (virtual_recvbuff == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Receiver buffer mmap failed\n");
    }
    if (virtual_fifo == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Fifo mmap failed\n");
    }
    memset(virtual_address, 0, buffsize);
    memset(virtual_sendbuff, 0, buffsize);
    memset(virtual_recvbuff, 0, buffsize);
    memset(virtual_fifo, 0, buffsize);
    int head = 0, tail = 0;

    pthread_t sendth, recvth;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    arguments send_args;
    send_args.virtual_address = virtual_address;
    send_args.virtual_buffer = virtual_sendbuff;
    send_args.head = &head;
    send_args.tail = &tail;
    send_args.buffsize = buffsize;
    send_args.fifosize = fifosize;
    send_args.sockfd = sockfd;
    send_args.lock = &lock;
    send_args.verbose = verbose;

    arguments recv_args;
    recv_args.virtual_address = virtual_address;
    recv_args.virtual_buffer = virtual_recvbuff;
    recv_args.head = &head;
    recv_args.tail = &tail;
    recv_args.buffsize = buffsize;
    recv_args.fifosize = fifosize;
    recv_args.sockfd = sockfd;
    recv_args.lock = &lock;
    recv_args.verbose = verbose;

    start_time = clock();

    if (pthread_create(&sendth, NULL, sender, &send_args)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error creating sender thread\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (pthread_create(&recvth, NULL, receiver, &recv_args)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error creating receiver thread\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (pthread_join(sendth, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error joining sender thread\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (pthread_join(recvth, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error joining receiver thread\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
        close(sockfd);

    fprintf(stderr, "[+] Exit\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Actual output shows prints from the `recv` thread, while the send thread prints

> [*] Send  Head: %d    Tail: %d\n

almost always, and sometimes what it has to do.

Comment: If you read e.g. [this POSIX reference for `pthread_mutex_unlock`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_unlock.html) you will see that calling `pthread_mutex_unlock` on a mutex you don't own leads to *undefined behavior*. Now try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or actually stepping through your code in a debugger) to see if you ever attempt to unlock the mutex twice. Hint: You do.

Comment: And regarding the mutex, you lock it for quite large amounts of code. Try to keep the mutex locked as little and as quickly as you can.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see what you mean, thank you so much!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You should add your findings as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sender` function, you have code like this (much shortened)

```
if (*(args->head) != *(args->tail)) {
    // ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
    if (args->verbose > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[*] %f CPU Usage: %d\n", ((double)(clock() - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, GetCPULoad());
    }
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
```

That will lead to the `pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock)` will be called *twice* on the same lock, without locking in between.

As can be seen in e.g. [this POSIX reference for `pthread_mutex_unlock`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_unlock.html) attempting to unlock a mutex that isn't owned by your thread (like unlocking an already unlocked mutex, or unlocking a mutex held by another thread) leads to *undefined behavior*.

This needs to be avoided somehow, for example by putting the last unlock call inside an `else` clause:

```
if (*(args->head) != *(args->tail)) {
    // ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
    if (args->verbose > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[*] %f CPU Usage: %d\n", ((double)(clock() - start_time)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, GetCPULoad());
    }
}
else {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(args->lock);
}
```